# How to have just one git in the root directory that works for multiple submodule project

Tags: git

I have created a project (Registration) with two submodules on my computer,
root directory (registration-service) (have .git),
--> submodele1 : Springboot application (have its own .git)
--> submodule2 : React typescript application (uses the root directory .git)

**Problem**: When I run in Intellij terminal **git add .**, it adds only the root directory and the React module.

**Question**: How do I make use of only the .git in the root directory?

**PS:** I would prefer to delete the git in the Springboot module and use only the git in root directory for both module.

[project structure in intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SML0t.png)

[Root directory structure with .git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIyH3.png)

[Springboot module structure with its own .git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qBbn.png)

> I deleted the .git in the Springboot module, thereafter, I ran init git in the root directory, added the repository and commit message. then I ran git add. which added on the root directory and the React module. After some search only, I ran git add --all which added on the Springboot module.

Comment: I had a similar problem. I had to do git rm submodule. https://devconnected.com/how-to-clear-git-cache/#:~:text=Clear%20Git%20Cache%20using%20rm,-Usually%2C%20you%20want&text=The%20easiest%20way%20to%20clear,remove%20an%20entire%20working%20directory.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @SteveTomlin thanks for your comment but it didn't work